# web workers with stenciljs for custom events

Tags: stenciljs

I want my components to listen to custom events on worker thread.

Is there a way to work with web workers with stenciljs to handle custom events ?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to implement [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) in Web Components, just like the way you would do without.

***my-web-component.js***

```
...
connectedCallback() {
    const worker = new Worker('doWork.js');

    worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
       console.log(e.data);
    }, false);
}
...
```

**doWork.js**

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  var data = e.data;
  switch (data.cmd) {
    case 'average':
      var result = calculateAverage(data); // Some function that calculates the average from the numeric array.
      self.postMessage(result);
      break;
    default:
      self.postMessage('Unknown command');
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks StefanN and sorry for the responding delay. Any idea with .TS instead .JS ?

Comment: Anytime :) What do you want to know regarding to TS?

Comment: @StefanN: Forget about the TS stuff. In StencilJS it build the .ts files in a number of js files (with names that are unknown to the user) like some people do with webpack (I think this uses webpack but I haven't checked). So to do it the old fashioned way like you show won't work. It's the same problem Angular has with web workers.
I am also having trouble with how to make web workers work. In Angular there is a npm package that does it for you.